# For loop bounds in Multi Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-3.0

I have a main thread that makes some other threads in two nested for.

```
private void mainthread()
        {
            List<Thread> ts= new List<Thread>();

            for (int w=0; w<7; w+=2)
                for (int h = 0; h < 5; h+=3)
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { otherthreads(w, h); });
                    ts.Add(t);
                    t.Start();
                }
            for (int i = 0; i < ts.Count; i++)
                ts[i].Join();
        }

        private void otherthreads(int w, int h)
        {                    
            listBox1.Invoke(new singleparam(addtolistbox), new object[] { "w:" + w.ToString() + ",h:" + h.ToString() });        
        }
```

Each thread adds it's input arguments to a Listbox. I am confused why the input arguments of some threads are not in the for bounds?

[image]

Comment: Because the loop variable has been "captured" by the anonymous method, so even when the loop ends, you still have other threads picking up its value.

Comment: you'r right. But why the initial values are not in the list. I mean w=0 and h=0?

Comment: Probably because the main thread continues to execute before any of the child threads start, so the "initial" values are never executed upon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop is running correctly, but what is happening is this:  the delegate knows that it must pass `w` and `h` onto the `otherthreads()` function, but those *values* are not bound until it is actually invoked.  In other words, prior to the delegate actually executing, it just knows it must use `w` and `h`.  On your last iteration, you are asking for the delegate to execute, but before it can, `w` and `h` increment for the final time on the initiating thread, causing their values to be 8 and 6, respectively.  The loops exit.  Then, picomoments later, the delegate executes and NOW has the values of `w` and `h`...  but the values are now 8 and 6.

You can avoid this by "snapshotting" `w` and `h` with local variables to the tightest scope around the delegate and assigning their values appropriately:

```
for (int h = 0; h < 5; h+=3) 
{
    int h2=h;
    int w2=w;

    Thread t = new Thread(delegate() { otherthreads(w2, h2); });
    ts.Add(t);
    t.Start();
}
```